# JavaFX animation is choppy

Tags: javafx

JavaFX animation is choppy.

And when i use
`stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`
animations become more choppy.

```
package com.test;

import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Pane root = new Pane();



        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50,10,10);




        Duration cycleDuration = Duration.millis(5000);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(cycleDuration,
                        new KeyValue(rect.widthProperty(),500,Interpolator.LINEAR))
        );

        timeline.setCycleCount(2000);
        timeline.play();




        root.getChildren().add(rect);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 650);


        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

How it works: https://youtu.be/UwoNByw-HYE

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz   3.19 GHz

16,0 Gb

Windows 10

Java 19

Javafx 19

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950 2Gb

I tried to make the same app with Qt QML, and it works really smooth and without ANY chopping.
Here's the comparation with Qt QML (bottom) and JavaFX (top) https://youtu.be/YAcI05NkjAE. JavaFX is jerky compared to Qt QML

**UPDATE:**
JavaFX app use GPU 10% and CPU 6% (with jerks)

Qt qml app use GPU 4% and CPU 2% (works prefect)

Comment: It's not possible to tell what is caused by your code, and what is artifacts introduced by the screen capture/video compression. Post a [mre] that we can use to reproduce the issue on our own machines.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This runs pretty smoothly on my system. I *maybe* see a couple of tiny glitches on the first cycle, which go away (I suspect this is caused by the JIT kicking in). Can you include some details of the system you're running on?

Comment: @James_D I've updated post. i think many people doesn't notice any chopping, but i noticed it. It chopping pretty close to the video

Comment: Again, it's very smooth on my system (same Java/JavaFX, Macbook Pro M1 Max). I'll leave it to someone with a more similar system to test.

Comment: @James_D here's the comparation with Qt QML (bottom) and JavaFX (top) https://youtu.be/YAcI05NkjAE. Do you see the difference or only i see it? JavaFX is jerky compared to Qt QML

Comment: Is if choppy on your system only when `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` is used?

Comment: @jewelsea not only when `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`. When `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` it is just more jerky. I tested this code today in my college (Windows 7, hardware worse than mine), and it works the same, as on my system. You see, this works really close to smooth, but every around 0.5 s a little jerk happens and i really hate it.

Comment: Try switching on the [pulse logger](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2548073/how-to-enable-internal-logging-for-javafx), `-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true`, and see if it provides any useful information.  There are other [undocumented and unsupported switches](https://adamish.com/blog/archives/320) you could play  around with that might provide further insight.

Comment: With the pulse logger output on my system (also a mac), the first couple of frames take about 50ms each as the system warms up, but after that, frames are regularly rendered every 16 or 17 milliseconds (e.g. at the default framerate of 60fps with no pauses), and most of that time is spent waiting for the next pulse to arrive, the actual time spent in JavaFX code between each frame is measured between 0 and 1 millisecond.

Comment: If your monitor is capable of a greater than 60fps refresh rate and you can perceive that, then you could either disable the frame rate cap by setting `javafx.animation.fullspeed` (just for a test, not production code), or set a different default frame rate target by setting `javafx.animation.framerate`.

Comment: @jewels pusles update around every 16 ms. After i used `javafx.animation.framerate` i didn't see the difference.

Comment: @jewels and `javafx.animation.fullspeed` didn't changed anything

Comment: That means that whatever the issue is, it isn’t related to the framerate, nor JavaFX pulse processing. Perhaps it is in the handover of the frames to the video card and their subsequent display to the monitor that there is some delay, but I don’t know why that would be.  Perhaps enabling vsync in the JavaFX system or the video driver  may help, though I don’t have the expertise for that.

Comment: From this blog [default JavaFX vsync setting is true](http://werner.yellowcouch.org/log/javafx-8-command-line-options/), you could disable it and maybe animation may be smoother but with more tearing.  Vsync also depends on monitor and video driver support I think.

Comment: @jewelsea so strange.. nothing of these arguments work. Nothing changed.. Only `javafx.pulseLogger=true` works

Comment: Yeah, I realize playing around with the undocumented arguments is just shots in the dark without knowing what the real issue is.  What it does though, is either, one setting works, therefore you have a solution or workaround or a setting doesn't work which can help eliminate some potential sources of issues.  In the previously linked blog, the rendering issue was fixed by setting `-Dprism.dirtyopts=false`, to workaround what at the time was a bug in the dirty region calculations, but that would seem an unlikely fix for your simple animation.

Comment: If you wish to discuss this further with the JavaFX developers, you could try posting to the [openjfx-dev](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) mailing list, my guess is that there is some history there around these kinds of issues and potential troubleshooting, fixes or workarounds that could be performed.

Comment: Hardware acceleration can be disabled completely by switching to the software rendering pipeline `-Dprism.order=sw`.  Not good for performance, so probably not a production setting, but would isolate whether the issue only occurs when the direct3d pipeline is used. Software rendering should handle the simple animation fine.  The other reports of smooth operation so far are all using macs which use a different pipeline (opengl es2).

Comment: @jewelsea Hey! I decided to return to this theme. javafx.animation.fullspeed is actually works. At first time I applyed this by a wrong way. Thank you very much. I think, I should play with -Djavafx.animation.pulse and -Djavafx.animation.framerate. Today I tested this at around 5 machines on Windows and this works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There definitely are visible glitches in the upper bar of the second video at irregular intervals of approximately one second length. Just concentrate on the right moving border of the bar. Some people just don't see or ignore them but others feel extremely disturbed by them. It seems to depend a bit on what you are used to. People who have a mobile or gaming background seem to be much more sensitive to such glitches than people with a primarily office PC background. Android once had project butter to overcome such glitches but JavaFX never did the same and still suffers from such glitches. (I know I won't make friends with this statement but it's true.) I also don't see anything obvious in your code that could directly improve the situation.

Edit: I have run your code on my Mac now and I have to admit that I do not see any glitches there. But I have seen the behaviour you describe very often myself. Of course it will always depend on your machine too.

Comment: So, there's no any solution at this time, right? After i google it, i didn't found any solution. I like JavaFX because i have an experience of it. Qt QML is the smoothest crossplatform desktop framework with low memory and cpu usage, but i don't have any experience of it and C++.

Comment: As I said already in the Edit above, I don't see the glitches on my Mac so it may also be something machine or OS specific in your case.